# How to disable button but not the current within the tableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableview and within the tableView I have a button and I want to disable other buttons for a second as some background process is happening on click of the button but during this I want to disable other buttons how can I achieve this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InnerOptionsCell") as! ProfileInnerOptionsTableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    var dictionary = [String: Any]()
    dictionary = accountList[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.row
    if dictionary["status"] as? Bool ?? false {
        cell.myButton.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        cell.myButton.isEnabled = false
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when you tap your button you update all the objects held in `accountList` you could loop over the tableView's `visibleCells` and update the states e.g.

```swift
func updateButtons() {
    guard let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows else {
        return
    }
    
    indexPaths
        .map { ($0, tableView.cellForRow(at: $0) as? ProfileInnerOptionsTableViewCell) }
        .forEach { (indexPath, cell) in
            cell?.button.isEnabled = accountList[indexPath.row]?["status"] as? Bool ?? false
        }
}
```

You could call a function similar to the above after you update your model setting all status' to `false` and then again when you set the status' back to `true`